# Code gives different result on OS and Windows

Tags: html, macos

I'm trying to understand why my code gives a slightly different result on a Windows PC and Mac OS.
The correct way is the Mac OS way. On Mac it's display as it should. See Picture 1.

Now for some reason it's different on a Windows machine. See picture 2.
The logo is bigger, the text isn't nicely aligned.

Anyone any idea what causes this?

Comment: This is probably a browser difference, not a OS difference. What browsers?

Comment: Sorry, it's not in the browser but in the email client. And it drives me "nuts"

Comment: Then what clients did you try it on?

Comment: Apple mail. When I sent a mail from Apple mail to Apple mail it looks as it should, see picture 1. When I sent a mail from Apple mail to Outlook on a Windows computer it looks like picture 2. The way it looks in Picture 2 looks bad and very unprofessional. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Where it's being sent from likely has nothing to do with it. This is probably an issue with the default padding that each client uses when it parses the HTML. Did you try explicitly adding padding to the elements?

Comment: No I haven't. I will try it an let you know.

Comment: I deleted my answer. And what you did to fix it to help future people with the same problem.

Comment: The lign up issue is still there but the picture issue is gone. All I did was replacing the current img line with "<img height="55" src="http://jobsbe.be/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/AJ-Recruit-300x83.png" style="width:200px;height:55px;" width="200" />" and that did the job. Picture is correct size on Apple mail and any other platform